# JwtAuthorizationToken doesn't have request.getPrincipal()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to make a login/registration in Spring Boot but I'm facing some problems.

Registration and login works just fine, but I want to check and verify the token at every request sent.

This is the **JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter**:

```
package com.example.springsecurityproject.jwt;

import com.example.springsecurityproject.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.service.TokenService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Encoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.checkerframework.checker.units.qual.A;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@AllArgsConstructor
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private TokenService tokenService;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {

            UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest =
                    new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            );

            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            return authenticate;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecretKey key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
        String secretKey = Encoders.BASE64.encode(key.getEncoded());
        tokenService.addToken(secretKey, (UserEntity) authResult.getPrincipal());
        String JWTtoken = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new java.util.Date())
                .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(2)))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretKey.getBytes()))
                .compact();


        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + JWTtoken);
    }
}
```

In this when the Key is created I'm saving it into a database where there is the encrypted key and the UserEntity (as foreign key).

In the **JwtVerifierToken** I'm usign a function **getKeyByUser** that just take the key when I pass the UserEntity, but the method **request.getUserPrincipal()** returns null, that means I can't have the key and also cannot verify.

```
package com.example.springsecurityproject.jwt;

import com.example.springsecurityproject.entity.TokenEntity;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.entity.UserEntity;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.repository.TokenRepository;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.service.UserService;
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Key;

public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    private UserService userService;

    public JwtTokenVerifier(TokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }
        try {

            TokenEntity key = tokenRepository.getKeyByUser((UserEntity) request.getUserPrincipal());
            String token = authorizationHeader.replace("Bearer", "");
            Jws<Claims> claimsJws = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey((Key) key).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
            Claims body = claimsJws.getBody();
            String username = body.getSubject();
        }
        catch (JwtException e){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Token non verificato");
        }

    }
}
```

This is the **ApplicationSecurityConfig**

```
package com.example.springsecurityproject.security;

import com.example.springsecurityproject.jwt.JwtTokenVerifier;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.jwt.JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.repository.TokenRepository;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.springsecurityproject.service.TokenService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.*;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenService tokenService;
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                //.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()) (per averlo abilitato)
                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(tokenService,authenticationManager()))
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(tokenRepository),JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
                /*
                Form Based Login
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/courses", true)
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                    .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(31))//default 2 weeks
                    .key("verysecurekey")
                    .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
                */
    }
    /*
    @Override
    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        UserDetails vitoUser = User.builder()
                .username("vito")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                //.roles(STUDENT.name())
                .authorities(STUDENT.getGrantedAuthorities())
                .build();

        UserDetails ddbdevUser = User.builder()
                .username("ddbdev")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                //.roles(ADMIN.name())
                .authorities(ADMIN.getGrantedAuthorities())
                .build();

        UserDetails marioUser = User.builder()
                .username("benmar")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                //.roles(MODERATOR.name())
                .authorities(MODERATOR.getGrantedAuthorities())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                ddbdevUser,
                vitoUser,
                marioUser
        );
    }
*/
}
```

Can someone help? I'm stuck :(

Comment: why are you not using the built in JWTFilter that comes with spring security?

Comment: I prefer using jjwt, it’s better to handle @Toerktumlare

Comment: ”Better to handle”? You do know that writing custom security is bad practice?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and write that bad, I'll partecipate in a project where they use JJWT instead of the normal JWTFilter, so I'm trying to being confident with it before starting, but I'm seeing that this library has some features for security for "better managing", that's what I was talking about. Anyway even if I would use the JWTFilter the authorization would be null too, unfortunately that's not the problem @Toerktumlare

Comment: Please update your code to use the way spring security recommends the handling of JWTs. All you need to do is to read the spring security documentation JWT chapter and not outdated tutorials online

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that the JwtTokenFilter doesn’t get the authorization, using Spring security Jwt handling or using JJWT doesn’t change anything.

Comment: `Spring security Jwt handling or using JJWT doesn’t change anything` is completely untrue. So what you are claiming is that spring has a resource server implementation that doesnt work? Thats a bold claim. I know de facto that following the documentation does work. Im telling you what is bad practice. Learn from it. Good luck with your problem

Comment: I'm not saying that, absolutely, taking the sentence without the context may misleads, I'm saying that the problem is not on the JWT, but is onto the authentication, the filter cannot get the authentication.
On **JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter** returns the actual authentication but into **JwtTokenVerifier** returns null. that's the problem. @Toerktumlare

Comment: You dont have to explain anything for me, the problem is that you are writing custom security which is bad practice. Learn to do it the right way first, before you go about doing custom things, good luck